# PostGIS error during a simple SELECT statement: Geometry SRID (2056) does not match column SRID (21781)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, windows-10

I am facing a strange error in a PostgreSQL 13.6 + PostGIS 3.2.0 database on a Window 10 machine:

```
mydb=# SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_view;
ERROR:  Geometry SRID (2056) does not match column SRID (21781)
```

These are the lines appearing in the PostgreSQL log file when the query is executed:

```
2023-09-27 09:53:56 CEST [2872] ERROR:  22023: Geometry SRID (2056) does not match column SRID (21781)
2023-09-27 09:53:56 CEST [2872] LOCATION:  postgis_valid_typmod, gserialized_typmod.c:162
2023-09-27 09:53:56 CEST [2872] STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_view;
2023-09-27 09:53:56 CEST [3880] ERROR:  55000: could not map dynamic shared memory segment
2023-09-27 09:53:56 CEST [3880] LOCATION:  ParallelWorkerMain, d:\pginstaller_13.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\access\transam\parallel.c:1306
2023-09-27 09:53:56 CEST [7160] LOG:  00000: background worker "parallel worker" (PID 3880) exited with exit code 1
2023-09-27 09:53:56 CEST [7160] LOCATION:  LogChildExit, d:\pginstaller_13.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\postmaster\postmaster.c:3738
```

Here is some other information which may be useful:

```
mydb=# SELECT Find_SRID('my_schema', 'my_view', 'geometry');
 find_srid
-----------
      2056
(1 line)
```

```
mydb=# SELECT distinct(ST_SRID(geometry)) FROM my_schema.my_view;
 st_srid
---------
    2056
(1 line)
```

Version information:

```
mydb=# SELECT version();
                          version
------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 13.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
(1 line)
```

and:

```
mydb=# SELECT postgis_full_version();
                                                                           postgis_full_version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="3.2.0 3.2.0" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.10.1-CAPI-1.16.0" PROJ="7.2.1" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" TOPOLOGY
(1 ligne)
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: What data do you have in the geometry_columns table for my_schema.my_view, if any? Does your view perhaps run ST_Transform?

Comment: Can you show the view creation code?

Comment: You can get a similar error if you cast within the view (`SELECT geom::geometry(point,3857)`) though it would also throw this error when checking the distinct SRID, and the casted SRID (3857 in my example) would have been reported by `find_srid`)

Comment: Hmm, indeed, I see this line in the view creation code: `st_force2d(pipe.geometry)::geometry(LineString,21781) AS geometry2d,` but I cannot simply re-run the creation of the view while changing the SRID in there because it raises: `ERROR: cannot change data type of view column "geometry2d" from geometry(LineString,21781) to geometry(LineString,2056)`

Comment: yes, if you change any column type, you must drop+recreate the view. It is important to keep the cast (else it becomes a generic srid-less geometry), but maybe you want to `st_transform` first, or to use the srid of the underlying table geometry.